# Proxy server, URLfilter, squid

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, firewall, squid

I'm looking for i believe a proxy server to integrate it in our company to filter the internet  more granulary than ipcop+urlfilter(what we now use) allows us.
What we try to achieve is to be able to filter some webpages for some users/pcs, whole net for some users/pcs.
We use AD in a win2008r2 environment.
Webgui is a must since managing rules in files is a pain in the back.

Now what exaclty am i looking for? i'm installing quintolabs to see what offers but i'm not sure if that is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

We work with win2008r2 servers too.

We have

> Squid3 + Winbind + CLamAV

This configuration allow us to have transparent LDAP/KERBEROS authentication for
Active Directory users and all the traffic is monitorized by ClamAV antivirus.

Everything is opensource and free of course.

You can have advanced access-rules for authenticated users to allow/deny traffic
to whitelisted/blacklisted pages.

You can also install on the linux machine the package

> WEBMIN

You can easily manage squid3 through a web UI so you dont have to manage
access-list in a file, just using the web interface.

I dont know what else you need to know. If you give us more information maybe
I can tell you more.